# Can two characters be added or subtracted?

Tags: c, char

I came across this snippet of code which outputs the following. I need to know that can two characters be added or subtracted from each other and how?

```
char Ch = 'A'; 
 printf("%c",Ch+'a'-'A');
```

`Output : a`

Comment: Sure thing they can be added and subtracted.

Comment: Google for ASCII.

Comment: Just an interesting fact: `'a'`  has a type of `int`.

Comment: ASCII isn't really relevant. The code here has the same behavior regardless of character encoding as long as arithmetic on `char` values can't overflow `int`.

Comment: Yes. `char` is an integer type and all operators that can be applied to integer types  can be applied to `char` operands as well.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 17 **The type char**, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the
>   enumerated types **are collectively called integer types**. The
>   integer and real ﬂoating types are collectively called real types.

and

> 18 **Integer and ﬂoating types are collectively called arithmetic
>   types**. Each arithmetic type belongs to one type domain: the real
>   type domain comprises the real types, the complex type domain
>   comprises the complex types.

and (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 2 **For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type**,
>   or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the
>   other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding
>   1.)

So in this expression

```
Ch+'a'-'A'
```

all operands have arithmetic types. The object Ch has the type `char`  that in this expression is converted implicitly to the type `int` due to the integer promotions. The character integer constants `'a'` and `'A'` have the type `int`.

So the expression is evaluated using internal representations of the character constants and of the object `Ch` converted to the type int. Then the result of the expression is outputted as a character object using the gotten value as an internal representation of an object of the type `char`

To make it more clear consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char Ch = 'A';

    printf( "%c = %d, "
            "%c = %d, "
            "%c + %c - %c = %d  + %d - %d => "
            "%d = %c\n",
            Ch, Ch, 
            'a', 'a', 
            Ch, 'a', 'A', Ch,  'a', 'A', 
            Ch + 'a' - 'A', Ch + 'a' - 'A' );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
A = 65, a = 97, A + a - A = 65  + 97 - 65 => 97 = a
```

Comment: You did not mention the ASCII table to relate the character to their respective integer values. Was that intentional? Are there other platforms (even if theoretically) where 'A' -for example- would have a different value than 65?

Comment: @AdamZahran For example IBM mainframes use the EBCDIC coding table.

Comment: Wow, never heard of that. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamZahran The C standard does not even guarantee that the letter characters `'a'` .. `'z'` (or uppercase letters) have contiguous codes. Only the decimal digits (`'0'` .. `'9'`) are guaranteed to have contiguous codes by the Standard.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  Thank you for the great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

They can be added and subtracted because they're integers. Assuming no overflow (which doesn't happen here) the commutative law applies and, `Ch+'a'-'A'` is `Ch-'A'+'a'`, and thus `0+'a'` or just `'a'`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can be added and subtracted. For example considering capital alphabets A-Z their ASCII values ranges from **65(A)** to **90(Z)**. So if you write: `printf("%c",'A'+ 2)` it will give you result as `C` what happens is it adds **2** to the ASCII value of `A` i.e. **65** so it becomes **67** which is the ASCII value of `C` so the result produced is `C`.

Now coming to your case `printf("%c",Ch+'a'-'A');`. Here ASCII values of `A` is **65** and `a` is **97**. So what your above statement becomes is **(65+97-65) = (97)** and since you have written `"%c"` it will print character value of **97** i.e. `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by knowing ASCII code of each. Math operations happen on the ASCII values.